# Get object key-value pairs from AxiosResponse in NestJS

Tags: axios, nestjs

I'm working on a small NestJS application for learning purposes.

I'm using `@nestjs/axios` as the documentation suggests. I'm able to reach the db (and do all CRUD operations) and send data back to the client with the following solutions:

```
async getUser(username: string): Promise<Observable<AxiosResponse<{ _id: string; _rev: string; email: string; name: string }>>> {
  return this.httpService.get(`${environment.cloudantBaseUrl}/users/${username}`).pipe(map((response) => response.data));
}
```

I need to get the email key-value pair from this response data object, but when I try to reach it, I get the following error:

> Property 'email' does not exist on type 'Observable<AxiosResponse<{ _id: string; _rev: string; email: string; name: string; }, any>>'.

I tried this way:

```
const user = await this.getUser(username);

console.log(user.email);
```

When I log the user constant to the console I get this signature:

```
Observable {
  source: Observable { _subscribe: [Function (anonymous)] },
  operator: [Function (anonymous)]
}
```

So my question is: how can I extract certain key-value pairs from the AxiosResponse object?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. No need to use `async/await` when using an Observable directly. If you want `async/await`, you need to wrap the Observable in `lastValueFrom()` to make it a promise. If you don't go with `lastValueFrom` you can drop the `async` in the method declaration and the `Promise<>` in the return type
2. As you're mapping the response already, you shouldn't be using `AxiosResponse<>`. Just do `Observable<{ _id: string; _rev: string; email: string; name: string }>`
3. To make use of an Observable in a later function, you just need to keep using `.pipe()` and rxjs operators like `map`, `switchMap`, and `tap`. [learnrxjs.io](https://learnrxjs.io) is a good resource for learning what these operators can do.

   1. When you're wanting to log the value of an observable, you use the `tap` operator. `.pipe(tap(console.log))` is a quick bind for it

Comment: Thank you. Now I can reach key-value pairs from the response.data object but unfortunately, I can't save these values outside of the scope for later use. Can you suggest a way to do that?

Comment: Why do you need to save it outside the scope? Like I said, if you're using observables you do everything inside the observable pipes.

Comment: I need to do some conditional checks with the response data. Then I want to return a whole different value in this function, depending on the checks.

Comment: So either do it in the observable pipe using the `map` operator (the website I linked to has great examples on several of the operators you can use) or transform it to a promise and use `async/await` like I said in the first point.

Comment: Thank you! I've transformed it into a promise, works like a charm.